# Python while loop ( until data exist )

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I was searching for different ways of using a **WHILE** loop or **FOR** loop for the problem which I'm currently facing.

I'm looking for pending (checking) loop

I have code which sends the request and receives an output, which is an empty field or date when the report created.

Idea is to do something like this:

```
WHILE generatedDate is None:
 run the script which gets information if it None
    IF generatedDate is not None
    Another bit of code which will download the report which just created
```

Does code should looks like this??

```
while x is None
#Do stuff
   if x is not None
   #Do other stuff
```

The answer was exactly what I was looking for, sorry for not providing full detailed information.

```
import time

#This part I made to access API and receive up to date JSON file
def get_data():
    data=None #Initially no data
    return data
#This section was modified to def download_report
def treat_data(data):
    #do the stuff when you got data, in your case download the report
    pass

#Check if data received
generatedData=get_data()

#Loop for pinging when data will be filled in.
while generatedData==None:

    #Pingin text
    print "waiting data"

    generatedData=get_data()

    #Wating time between checks
    time.sleep(0.25)


#download_report call after exiting the loop (after field become not empty)
treat_data(generatedData) #report generated
```

Comment: u have pseudo code then whats the problem

Comment: It would be is `None` not `in`

Comment: @Roushan I could not figure out how to write the actual code. The struggle part in this code is 'None', how to create code which will check 1) that data do not exist and 2) that it exists. Because usually, the solutions are like this (while x > 2) where you have the actual value which will increase or decrease.

Comment: [while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)  and  [more on while](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) and basically [start here:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) .. SO is no tutorial site that teaches basics of a  language. We care about specific problems _if_ you already did your research on this and other site and are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that ?

```
import time

#this function will return None if no data, and return the data if you got data
def get_data():
    #here we do stuff to verify if we got data
    data=None #we suppose there is no data
    return data

def treat_data(data):
    #do the stuff when you got data, in your case download the report
    pass

#check first if we got data
generatedData=get_data()

#then waiting until you get data
while generatedData==None:

    #check again if we got data
    print "waiting data"

    generatedData=get_data()

    #wait 0.25s between two check
    time.sleep(0.25)

#here we assume we got data (because we leave the while loop)
#so we treat the data
treat_data(generatedData)
```

As we don't implement the func get_data, this script will return :

```
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
waiting data
[...]
```

Comment: Thak you for this. That's exactly what was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

while should be in lower case and it should have a condition like 
       while(var == true):
                     ...